# Summing Segments of a Dataframe Column Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to loop through my DataFrame to create 5 year future returns from each initial i. My code is as follows, but it gives me the Error: Invalid Syntax.

```
list = ['aapl','tsla','vz','t']

df = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo(list, start = start_of_interval, end = end_of_interval, interval = data_interval)['Adj Close']
df = DataFrame(df)
df['Returns'] = df.pct_change()
l = df.index.values 
for i in range(0,len(l)):
   df.loc[l[i], '5YearReturn'] = df.cumsum(df.loc[l[i], "Returns"]:df.loc[l[i+1824], "Returns"])
```

Can I not use cumsum in this way?

Comment: Can you post sample data, code to create your df and what your desired output should look like

Comment: I added some additional code for creating the df.  The desired output would be a column that signifies the 5 year future return from each given starting point (i.e. the 5 year future return starting from row 1, then the 5 year future return starting from row 2.)